# Multiple wordpress installations on same server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have three different wordpress sites on my server located like this:

/www -> main site

/www/site2/

/www/site3/

The main site is working but the site2 and site3, which are the wordpress sites inside the folder aren't. I'm getting the following error on site2 and site3, I think it has to do with the htaccess:

`Warning: include(modules/.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/index.php on line 154`

`Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'modules/.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /www/index.php on line 154`

I have the htaccess on /www/site2/ configured like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how should I configure the htaccess?

Comment: You could also have one network installation of WordPress as it will be easyer on maintnance. Here is some documentation on that http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /site2/` for `/www/site2/` and to `RewriteBase /site3/` for `/www/site2/`

Comment: I've just did that but still get the error pointing to `/www/index.php`

Comment: On wp settings: `wordpress url: www.mysite.com/site2` and `web (URL):www.mysite.com/site2`